# How to declare start date and end date using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Master_Barang
WHERE
(@KodeBarang='ALL' OR Kode_barang = @KodeBarang)
 AND ((@TanggalStart = 'ALL' Or Convert(Varchar,CreatedOn,112)&gt;=@TanggalStart) And (@TanggalEnd = 
'ALL' Or Convert(Varchar,CreatedOn,112)&lt;=@TanggalEnd))
 ORDER BY Kode_barang ASC
```

How do I declare the start date and end date in MySQL with a query like this?
Thank you.

Comment: where are start and end date columns located what's the column name.. you should at least provide with complete details.

Comment: actually the column name is CreatedOn but i made it into Tanggal Start and Tanggal End

Comment: you can use between operator more info https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: ok i will try it thanks